# Use a lot of phone

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

If someone is on phone all the time, can she use:

> I use a lot of phone, I have started acting like an addict.

Is the use of "use a lot of phone" natural in this context?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not natural. A more natural way to say it is

> I am always on the phone, I have started acting like an addict.

or

> I am on the phone so much that I have become addicted.

Comment: But a journalist from America uses it in her news article.    http://healthland.time.com/2013/12/06/do-you-use-your-cell-phone-a-lot-it-might-be-making-you-more-anxious/    And this one too:https://lifehacker.com/how-can-i-stop-using-my-phone-all-the-time-and-actually-5898612 @Weather Vane _"Do you use your Cell Phone a lot? It might be making you more anxious."_    It's the title of the article I linked. (The first  one)

Comment: The phrase "use your phone a lot" is not "use a lot of phone".

Comment: So can I say: I use my phone a lot.

Comment: Yes, you can say that.

Answer (score 1):

**The Vernacular is a Fast-Moving Train: Welcome to the Real World of Creative English**

Explanation of: **"use a lot of phone" as in:**

"I use a lot of phone,I have started acting like an addict."

Right, OK. **So in this day and age**, some people try to ***sound cute*** or **"with it"**. This is especially true of people on TV.

**This "use a lot of phone" is taken from a pre-existing pattern**:  "use a lot of product on my hair, use a lot of ketchup on my fries, use a lot of make-up on my face". Those are examples that come to mind using the same verb.

Here's the thing, and here I *am going to do that journalist one better* [idiom]:

**"I do a lot of phone**, I have started acting like an addict".

Because in the drug world, there are expressions such as: **to do pot, to do coke,to do hash** etc.

You might hear a pothead say: "Yeah, I do a lot of grass." for: "I smoke a lot of marijuana."

Since the phone is like a drug, **do a lot of phone** is funnier and more creative.

In any event, none of this is regular English. These are merely attempts to express oneself creatively and insofar as they tally with the language, they work fine.

I fear that sometimes these types of questions are misunderstood....

However, please note: this type of creative English is everywhere.

The normal way of saying it is: I'm on the phone a lot, I use my phone a lot, I talk a lot on the phone, etc.

Comment: Yes, any native speaker would understand it, but they would also hear it as 'wrong'. Being creatively wrong is important, and has a long tradition, but a person learning English generally wants to avoid sounding *wrong*.

Comment: No  hip native speaker would hear it as wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As one more possible tweak to the sentence that would make it natural, you could say:

> I use a lot of phone *time*.

That sentence would make sense in the context of mobile phone plans. Sometimes such plans also refer to *talk time*.

---

However, this is very contextual. It's not something you would normally say unless you were specifically referring to a phone plan—and the number of minutes you've used up.

But if you do use *phone time* or *talk time* in that sense, then it's a perfectly reasonable construction because both of those things are countable and can refer to a little or a lot.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not natural, or indeed entirely meaningful. The minimal change to make it some way natural (and semantically valid) is:

> I use (the/my) phone a lot, I have started acting like an addict.

You can't "use a lot of phone", because "phone" isn't something you can have "a lot" of. You could "use a lot of phones", but that would mean using many separate physical objects - and some grammatical purists would say you need to say "many" when it's a countable noun, rather than "a lot of". Another normal way to say that would use "use lots of phones". However, none of those mean what you are trying to say.

If someone often or excessively uses *something*, "**a lot**" is a correct way to indicate that, but it goes after the *something*. This is also true for verbs other than *to use*.

> I cook pasta a lot.
>
> I watch TV a lot.
>
> I play video games a lot.

Now, all of those could be said the way you're suggesting.

> I cook a lot of pasta.
>
> I watch a lot of TV.

In those two cases, the difference in meaning is subtle. Those forms of words are allowed because *pasta* and *TV* are (or can be) mass (uncountable) nouns. The first doesn't actually mean that you cook pasta often (which is what *cook pasta a lot* means), just that you get through a lot of pasta. You might cook it infrequently, but when you do you cook large amounts. The *watch TV* versions are almost interchangeable, because watching a given "quantity" of TV is actually synonymous with spending a certain amount of time watching it.

> I play a lot of video games.

This is like the pasta one, except video games aren't a mass noun so the meaning is a little more distinct. To "play video games a lot" means to spend a lot of time playing video games. To "play a lot of video games" literally means playing many different video games.